# dyndns ddclient client on ubuntu, how to do a basic installation?

Tags: dynamic-dns

I am setting up a web server in my home.  I have cable internet, the IP address changes, so I need to use dyndns.org.

My linux box is debian.  I am now at the last part of the dyndns.org ddclient installation.

The ddclient README says:

```
INSTALLATION:

  cp ddclient /usr/sbin/
  mkdir /etc/ddclient
  cp sample-etc_ddclient.conf /etc/ddclient/ddclient.conf
  vi /etc/ddclient/ddclient.conf
  -- and change hostnames, logins, and passwords appropriately

  ## For those using Redhat style rc files and using daemon-mode:
  cp sample-etc_rc.d_init.d_ddclient /etc/rc.d/init.d/ddclient
  ## enable automatic startup when booting
  /sbin/chkconfig --add ddclient
  ## start the first time by hand
  /etc/rc.d/init.d/ddclient start

  ## If you are not using daemon-mode, configure cron and dhcp or ppp
  ## as described below.
```

The problem is the line: 
  cp sample-etc_rc.d_init.d_ddclient /etc/rc.d/init.d/ddclient

Debian tells me:
  "Cannot create regular file /etc/rc.d/init.d/ddclient"

Why is that?  It is correct that /etc/rc.d/ does not exist.  What do I do?

Secondly, the install directory has these files:

```
sample-etc_rc.d_init.d_ddclient
sample-etc_rc.d_init.d_ddclient.redhat
sample-etc_rc.d_init.d_ddclient.ubuntu
```

Maybe I should be using the ubuntu file since that is my operating system?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install ddclient`